# What should be the TransactionIdPrefix for multiple spring boot consumer/produces apps which are connected to kafka (3 brokers))

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

I am having multiple spring boot applications which are connected to kafka (clustrized with 3 brokers)and also i integrated transaction synchronization (chainedKafkaTransactionManager). so i want to know should i give the same TransactionIdPrefix  value in kafka config  for all the multiple application or diffrent one.

i tried giving a random generated TransactionIdPrefix for each application. but i think in some time in multi thread environment in Listeners method it will take old data from database (jpa repositories)
is it problem because of diffrent TransactionIdPrefix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends; if they are multiple instances of the same app and the transactions are started by consumers, the prefix must be the same, so that zombie fencing is handled properly when partitions move from one instance to another after a rebalance.

If the transactions are started by producers, the prefix must be unique in each instance.

If they are different applications they should have different prefixes, regardless of what starts the transaction.